# Ludo board in java

Tags: java

[image]

How do I write code to this board without using an array? I tried, but I did not get the right result. It should be with functions, loops and conditional structures. Row=11, column=11.

```
public static void board(int size) {
    for (int i=1; i<=size;i++){
        for (int j=1; j<=size; j++){
            if (i==6 && j==6){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            else if ( i==5 || i==7 || j==5 || j==7 || i==6 && j==1 || i==6 && j==11 ||
                    i==1 && j==6 || i==11 && j==6){
                if (i==6 && j==7 || i==5 && j==6 || i==6 && j==5 || i==7 && j==6 ){
                    break;
                }else{
                    System.out.print("o");
                }
            }
            else if (i==6 || j==6 ) {
                System.out.print(".");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    board(11);
}
```

Comment: They are not the answers I want. The first one does not output this board correctly. From the second answer, I did not understand anything, I did not learn the this coding of the java yet. @Progman

Comment: Do not ask the same question twice. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: To clarify, you are expected to edit the previous question to improve it, rather than repost the question.

Comment: If you want to repost, then at least focus on what is still unclear. Mention your previous post and the code provided there that you did not get. Base your question on understanding this piece of code that is unclear to you. Do not jost repost the same question without adressing any of the mentioned issues, your old question was not closed for no reason. Please see [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        board(11);
    }

    public static void board(int size) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
                if ((i == 6 && j == 6)) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                } else if (i == 5 || i == 7 || j == 5 || j == 7 || i == 6 && j == 1 || i == 6 && j == 11
                        || i == 1 && j == 6 || i == 11 && j == 6) {
                    if (i == 6 && j == 5 || i == 6 && j == 7 || i == 5 && j == 6 || i == 7 && j == 6) {
                        System.out.print(".");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("o");
                    }
                } else if (i == 6 || j == 6) {
                    System.out.print(".");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
    ooo    
    o.o    
    o.o    
    o.o    
ooooo.ooooo
o.... ....o
ooooo.ooooo
    o.o    
    o.o    
    o.o    
    ooo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a general routine for any board size by detecting if the cell lies in one of the 4 corner blocks, in which case you print a space, on a center row or column, in which case you print a "." or a space if you're at the board center, otherwise you print a wall (O).

```
public static void board(int size)
{
    if(size % 2 == 0 || size <= 3)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Board size must be odd and bigger than 3: " + size);

    int center = (size+1)/2;
    int corner = (size-1)/2;
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++)
        {
            if(Math.max(i, j) < corner || 
               Math.max(Math.min(i, 1+size-i), j) < corner || 
               Math.max(i, Math.min(j, 1+size-j)) < corner || 
               Math.max(Math.min(i, 1+size-i), Math.min(j, 1+size-j)) < corner)
            {                   
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            else if((i > 1 && i < size && j == center) || (j > 1 && j < size && i == center))
            {
                if(i == center && j == center)
                    System.out.print(" ");
                else
                    System.out.print(".");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("O");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

board(7);

```
  OOO  
  O.O  
OOO.OOO
O.. ..O
OOO.OOO
  O.O  
  OOO
```

board(11);

```
    OOO    
    O.O    
    O.O    
    O.O    
OOOOO.OOOOO
O.... ....O
OOOOO.OOOOO
    O.O    
    O.O    
    O.O    
    OOO
```